# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. MemoryStream error

Tags: vb.net

I get this error when I'm converting an image into bytes using MemoryStream.
At first it was working fine but the third and fourth times I get this error.

```
Public Function getImgByte() As Byte()    'Convert image to array bytes
    Dim arrImg() As Byte
    ms2 = New MemoryStream()
    editStudentPicbox.Image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) ' Use appropriate format here
    arrImg = ms2.ToArray()
    ms2.Close()
    Return arrImg
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the memory stream is closed but it is not disposed from the memory. It is recommended to use Using clause . Try the following code:

```
Public Function getImgByte() As Byte()    'Convert image to array bytes
    Using  ms2 as New MemoryStream()
        editStudentPicbox.Image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) ' Use appropriate format here
        Return ms2.ToArray()
    End Using   
End Function
```

Or just add ms2.Dispose() after ms2.Close() but you have to declare ms2 every time in this function.

```
Dim ms2 as MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
```

Comment: cant try atm, any other reason for this error? at first time it was working fine but on 2nd or 4th try that error oiccurs

Comment: Just try adding ms2.Dispose() before returning a value